# CSS Styling that only Pertains to all IE and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to target a particular css styling for IE and Firefox. Based on what I have read, I can do the following that will target all IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

However, it does not appear to work on my end.

Also, is their a way to call a styling and it only target IE? For example, let say I have the following code:

```
<span class="title">WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW</span><br />
    <span class="styletext">Tuesday October 24, 2014</span>
```

And I want to add the following css and it will only work if the site is on IE:

```
<span class="title random(only for IE/Firefox)">WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW<br />
                <span class="styletext">Tuesday October 24, 2014 </span></span>
```

Is their a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Update:

The following is the cfm file that I am using to create the website. Currently, it is not responsive but in the process in doing that soon:

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/regalmedstyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap_override.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
<body onUnload="closePopUpWindow()">
        <cfinclude template="header.cfm">

        <cfinclude template="sbar_left.cfm">
            <!---Body of Page--->
            <div id="mainl">
                    <img src="img/blah.jpg" class="sideImg" />
                    <img src="img/blah2.jpg" class="sideImg" />
                    <img src="img/blah3" class="sideImg" />
                    <img src="img/bah4" class="sideImg" />
            </div>
        <div id="mainr">
                <span class="title">WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW<br />
                <span class="styletext">Tuesday October 24, 2014 </span></span>
                <br />
                <span class="sizetext">Susam facest, et fugit fugit doluptas simagnit opta pro qui ommodit laut magnis nis aborempor sin pro offictem qui consero blatis vellace stiore verae conseri optat.</span><br />
                <div class="spacingP">
                    <p class="sizetext">Ri dignati ut que sitatureped ut fugia ilia ne nobit, oditas erbis. Nos, unius in iam quod ducit grae orum se. </p>
                </div>
                <br />
                    <span class="title">WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW <br />
                    <span class="styletext">Tuesday October 24, 2014 </span></span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="sizetext">Susam facest, et fugit fugit doluptas simagnit opta pro qui ommodit laut magnis nis aborempor sin pro offictem qui consero blatis vellace stiore verae conseri optat.</span><br />
                    <div class="spacingP">
                        <p class="sizetext">Ri dignati ut que sitatureped ut fugia ilia ne nobit, oditas erbis. Nos, unius in iam quod ducit grae orum se. </p>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <span class="title">WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW<br />
                    <span class="styletext">Tuesday October 24, 2014 </span></span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="sizetext">Susam facest, et fugit fugit doluptas simagnit opta pro qui ommodit laut magnis nis aborempor sin pro offictem qui consero blatis vellace stiore verae conseri optat.</span><br />
                    <div class="spacingP">
                        <p class="sizetext">Ri dignati ut que sitatureped ut fugia ilia ne nobit, oditas erbis. Nos, unius in iam quod ducit grae orum se. </p>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <span class="title">WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW<br />
                    <span class="styletext">Tuesday October 24, 2014 </span></span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="sizetext">Susam facest, et fugit fugit doluptas simagnit opta pro qui ommodit laut magnis nis aborempor sin pro offictem qui consero blatis vellace stiore verae conseri optat.</span><br />
                    <div class="spacingP">
                        <p class="sizetext">Ri dignati ut que sitatureped ut fugia ilia ne nobit, oditas erbis. Nos, unius in iam quod ducit grae orum se. </p>
                    </div>
                    <br />
        </div>
        <cfinclude template="sbar_right.cfm">   
</body>
<!---   <cfinclude template="footer.cfm">--->  
</html>
```

The following is the css file. I do apologize how messsy it is. Will be cleaning it up today, just started today:

CSS:

```
html, body { font-family: "OpenSans", sans-serif; }

body{
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p{
    font-size:10pt !important;
    display:inline;
}

.spacingP{
    margin-top: 6px;
}

a{
color:white;
}

ul{
list-style:none;
}

.linkFont{
    font-family:TradeGothic CondEighteen !important;
}

.img-banner{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:grey;
 }

#banner-wrapper{
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#FFF;
    background-image: url("../img/Banner.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom:83px;
}

.navbar-buttons{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align:right;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#mainl{
    float:left;
    padding:1px 0 0 0;
    width:10%;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#mainr{
    float:left;
    padding:1px 0 0 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 45px;
    width:30%;
}

img.sideImg{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 0 15px 7px;    
}

#sidebarleft{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0; margin:0;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#sidebarleft a:hover{
    color:green;
}

#sidebarleft ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
}

.leftbuttons{
    background-image: url("../img/Button_1.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 5px 0 8px 10px;
}

.leftbuttons a{
    color:grey; 
    font-size:10pt !important;
}

.leftbuttons2{
    background-image: url("../img/Button_2.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 7px 0 4px 7px;
}

.leftbuttons2 a{
    color:grey;
    vertical-align:center;
    font-size: 10pt !important;
}

#sidebarright{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0; margin:0;
    margin-top:15px;
}

#sidebarright a{
    color:grey;
    font-size:10pt !important;
}

#sidebarright a:hover{
    color:green;
}

.rightbuttons{
    background-image: url("../img/Button.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:  14px 0 20px 11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.rightbuttons2{
    background-image: url("../img/Button.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:  9px 0 19px 11px;
}

.rightbuttonsAlert{
    background-image: url("../img/Button.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:  12px 0 20px 11px;
}
.rightbuttonsAlert a{
    color:red !important;
}

.rightbuttonsAlert a:hover{
    color:blue !important;
}

.rightbuttonsDir{
    background-image: url("../img/Button.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:  9px 0 20px 11px;
}
.shifttd{
    padding-right:27.5px;
    padding-bottom:27.5px;
}

img.buttonUlti{
    float:right;
    margin-top:13px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.shiftRes{
    margin-left:27px;
    padding-top:40px;
}

.departstyle{
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family:calibri !important;
}

.resstyle{
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:15pt;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    font-family:calibri !important;
}

#content-wrapper{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.styletext{
    font-size:8pt !important;
    font-style:italic;
}

.sizetext{
    font-size: 8pt !important;
}

.title{
    font-size:9pt !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blue;
}

.shiftTitle{
    margin-top:5px;

}

/*MEDIA*/

@media screen and (max-width:939px){
    #banner-wrapper{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding:0;
        background-image: url("../img/Banner.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-bottom:83px;
    }
}
```

Images showing the issue. The following is the issue in IE that shows off spacing:

[image]

And the following image is in Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, the spacing among the content is off and not sure why
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Targeting specific browsers in CSS alone is not possible and IE conditional comments are often times used for specific older versions. I would avoid browser-targeting and try to come up with another, more universal solution.

Comment: @Quantastical I am having spacing issues on IE but in Chrome it looks fine. I will add the css and the cfm file

Comment: It might be better to provide the code and an example showing the spacing issue and ask "why is the spacing not the same between browsers?" or something to that effect. Anytime I find myself thinking I need to come up with some browser-specific hack, I tend to think that is not the right way to fix the problem.

Comment: @RobertoFlores - Q is right about finding a more general solution that works on all modern browsers. However, if you are absolutely in a corner, you can use the `CGI` scope in ColdFusion to find a browser's User Agent String (basically a browser's signature), and include different CSS depending on which User Agent CF is reading. They can be spoofed, so it isn't fool-proof, but generally only tech-savvy users would be doing that anyway.

Comment: Bootstrap does a lot of work to make pages look the same on all browsers. You are going to end up fighting what it does. I recommend using working with the Bootstrap CSS to get the look and feel you want. In your question, you note that you want to move to Responsive Design. This is another reason to not fight Bootstrap.

Comment: Why is the tagged as `ColdFusion`? This is not a ColdFusion issue.

Comment: Your first example is "conditional comments" which have been removed from IE as of version 9, I believe, so that's why they no longer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that different browsers have different "standard" CSS, for instance your `line-height` value in your pages are being interpreted differently, or are using a default setting that is specific browser to browser.

Your current method appears to be that if there is a problem in some browsers then you're trying to cancel out that exception by adding another exception, specific to that browser. This is not the best way of approaching this issue and is easy to snowball into loading more special cases for each browser.

## 1)

There are several options open to you to work around these inconsistencies, the easiest of which is to use [CSS Normalizer](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which should be loaded before your CSS stylesheet and will set a standard for all browsers, to show a page's elements all the same way.

## 2)

Alternatively you should set in your CSS *all* values so you are not relying on browser default settings, such as `line-height`, etc. You set each and every value that you notice is being browser-interpreted inconsistently (this is sort of what Normalize does).

so for example:

```
span {
    line-height:1.1rem;
}
```

This will superceed any browser default `line-height` value. Use Inspector in Chrome or [Firebug in Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) to view and assess the various CSS rules affecting each element on your page.

## 3)

You can also try and use Vendor Prefixes as [remarked here](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way) so that certain CSS rules are applied only to certain browsers, however the way these work is not set in stone and this is still the incorrect solution of trying to fix an exception with another exception.

Vendor prefixes for IE are `-ms-<property>`.

## 4)

In order to be backwards compatible with old (pre-9) IE and other older browsers then I recommend downloading and running [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) which will detect what CSS and styling features the browser can use and then fit the styles applied by the stylesheet to that specification.

I believe there is some ambiguous info. about if Modernizr runs well *with* CSS Normalizer so possibly use one or the other if there are any aspect overlap issues.

---

My strongest suggestion is that you use method **1** here. Method 2 is an option and method three simply an idea that may assist you.

Option **4** - Modernizr - fixed the issues with older pre-9 Internet Explorer displays.

Comment: I had added the normalizer.csss and it still didnt work and I dont get why? Sorry, still very new

Comment: I would recommend using a code inspector as referenced -- Firebug -- and exploring what code is actually applied to your pages in the browser, Firebug is Firefox specfic but it will give you a good idea if your CSS is being overwritten by other rules, etc.

Comment: Your code appears to be using Bootstrap which should have all these cross browser issues already covered in it, so perhaps you need to remove or further validate your CSS rules as perhaps rules you've set are causing the output to be inconsistent.

Comment: @RobertoFlores Also please look up using the `box-sizing` as that is something that markedy effects CSS output and is somewhat browser specific.

Comment: Will do and I use the debugger for IE and it works fine IE8 and above but not below, not sure if I should worry about below IE8 and I will look into box-sizing

Comment: @RobertoFlores ok for old IE issues you may be better off using something called `Modrnizr`, please google it, and use it on your site to be a bit more backward compatible for things like CSS3 features and layouts.

Comment: @ Martin, I have looked into it. Thank you for you help and it worked out.

Comment: did Modrnizr fix your issue? If so I can edit my answer and add it in. Cheers @RobertoFlores

Comment: @ Martin: Yes, it helped me fix the issue

Comment: @RobertoFlores I have updated my answer with a link to Modernizr. Cheers :)